# Understanding Moxi stats field "total_connections"

Tags: couchbase, membase, moxiemanager

What do the following fields means in the Moxi stats counters?

I understand the "curr_connections" which counts both client connections into moxi and also moxi’s connections to downstream Couchbase servers.

What does the counter "total_connections" represent?

> STAT memcached:stats:curr_connections 1140
>   STAT memcached:stats:total_connections 884426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total connections is the number of connections that have been made to the server since you started the server. Obviously it resets when you restart. In addition, the total connections is normally far less than the total number of the get command stats because typically you connect to memcached and then send multiple get/set requests over the same connection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The moxi docs http://docs.couchbase.com/moxi-manual-1.8/#moxi-statistics do not explain every field in detail. It is a little hard to understand a few of the parameters. Is there any documentation explaining more about them?

Comment: Since it is just memcached stats, this explanation should do it. http://www.pal-blog.de/entwicklung/perl/memcached-statistics-stats-command.html

Comment: Just another query: 

curr_connections =1035
maxconns= 1024

How can curr_connections be greater than max_conns?